# How to get toolbar of an Activity of the Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-fragmentactivity

Android Fragment related query how we can use toolbar present inside the fragmentActivty inside the fragment which we replace in activity in framelayout

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

OR

```
Toolbar toolbar = getParentFragment().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

depending upon your situation.

Comment: i have already tried this but it giving me  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.Toolbar exception

Answer (score 0):

**I just notice that you're using `FragmentActivity`**

Important information found in the google docs for `FragmentActivity` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)):

```
Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you
should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this
one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.
```

If your using compatibility libraries then you'll want to extend `AppCompatActivity` ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html))

Look at the inheritance hierarchy for these classes, they both have `FragmentActivity`/`android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` as parents.  This might also be your issue.

---

**Original Answer:**

You can pass a reference of your `Activity` to your `Fragment` and then get a reference to the `Toolbar` there, e.g.:

In your activity:

```
// 'this' being the activity context
MyFragment theFragment = new MyFragment(this);
```

In your fragment:

```
// in fragment, use the reference passed in the constructor
myActivityReference.setActionBarTitle("My Title");

// or do this
Toolbar theToolbar = myActivityReference.getSupportActionBar();
theToolbar.doTheThingsIWant(...);
```

or

You could use the `getActivity()` method in fragment and cast it as your activity:

```
Toolbar theToolbar = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

I'm not sure if the cast is required... I can't remember.  Try it without if you like.